# Unity Measuring Real distance between two object

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello2,

I have a *(might be a really simple)* question that I cannot figure out.

How do i measure a distance between two object - visually not mathematically?

I know that i can use Vector3.Distance to measure the object's distance.
but its not what I am looking for.

To make it clearer, here is a graph of what i wanna achieve:
[image]

```
Vector3.Distance(cubeA.position, ball.position) //will give a result of 6 
Vector3.Distance(cubeB.position, ball.position) //will give a result of 4
```

Mathematically it is correct, that the ball is nearer to the cube B

But visually, **the ball should be closer to cube A**

Therefore how do i achieve to visually measure the distance?

*Unfortunately since the Cube will be procedural, I cannot just hardcoded it.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would need to factor in the scale into the equation. For example something like abs(cubePos - playerPos) - cubeScale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what do you want. Ball is closer to CubeA because its right side closer to ball than cubeB's left side.

If you add rigidbodies and boxcolliders to cube and send ray from ball to cubes you can find short distance from ball.

**For example**
I used line cast for this example.

```
Transform CubeB,CubeA,closest;   
RaycastHit hit;
float dist;

if (Physics.Linecast(transform.position, CubeA.position,out hit))
{
    dist= hit.distance;
    closest=CubeA;
}

if (Physics.Linecast(transform.position, CubeB.position,out hit))
{
    if(hit.distance>dist)
         dist= hit.distance;
         closest=CubeB;
}
```

Comment: This is an improvement, but bear in mind that this won't necessarily find the closest part of `CubeA` or `CubeB`, but instead finds the closest point on a straight-line path towards the center of each cube

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Although like @byxor said, that it only gives me a straight-line path.., at least i gives me an idea.. In the end I am projecting 24 linecast around a sphere and it works! ;D

Answer (score 1):

To have the exact evaluation distance you need you can consider to create the planes of your cube with the [plane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane-ctor.html) class.
Then you can obtain the distance with [Plane.ClosestPointOnPlane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.ClosestPointOnPlane.html), that is the smalles distance in plane's normal direction, the distance that you need.

If you know the side of your cube, you can construct that plane directly, or get the face/plane of interest using the 6 planes of the cube if the rotation of them is random at the time the distance needs to be evaluated.

For the logic to get the face of interest [Plane.GetSide](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.GetSide.html) to take into account specific cases where faces might be in conflict (corners of the cube)

Comment: Sorry @rustyBucketBay ,, I am not sure how to implement your idea... therefore I cannot really upvote your post.., but regardless thanks for the answer... ^_^